# Remove null from array using jolt

Tags: java, json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have some issue removing the null values from an array using jolt as describe bellow:

**Input**

```json
{
  "userId": "1",
  "age": "20",
  "firstName": "firstname1",
  "lastname": "lastname1",
  "zipCode": "zipcode1",
  "street": "street1",
  "city": "city1",
  "country": "country",
  "gender": "gender1",
  "grade": "grade1",
  "birthday": "birthday1"
}
```

**Jolt spec**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "userId": "ID",
      "age": "age",
      "firstName": "firstName",
      "lastname": "lastname",
      "gender": "gender",
      "grade": "grade",
      "birthday": "birthday",
      "street|city|zipCode|country": {
        "$": "address[#2].code",
        "@": "address[#2].value"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "ID": "1",
  "age": "20",
  "firstName": "firstname1",
  "lastname": "lastname1",
  "gender": "gender1",
  "grade": "grade1",
  "birthday": "birthday1",
  "address": [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
    {
      "code": "street",
      "value": "street1"
    },
    {
      "code": "city",
      "value": "city1"
    },
    {
      "code": "zipCode",
      "value": "zipcode1"
    },
    {
      "code": "country",
      "value": "country"
    }
  ]
}
```

I had some solutions suggested by @Barbaros thanks to him as describe in the link
[Remove null values from JSON output using Jolt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70382927/remove-null-values-from-json-output-using-jolt)

but still struggling with it, Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefix key-value pairs with a literal such as `adr_` in the first step, and then use within the last step to distinguish the rest of the attributes those will be sybolized by `"*":"&"` pair such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "userId": "ID",
      "*": "&",
      "street|city|zipCode|country": {
        "$": "adr_&.code",
        "@": "adr_&.value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "adr_*": "address[]"
    }
  }
]
```

where only `"userId": "ID"` written individually so as to rename it as desired.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Ozhan, thank you for your helpfull answer. I was wondring if it was possible to display another name in the value of code in the output: ex: address : [{"code":"new-field-name", "value": "street value"}, ....] ?

Comment: Hi @Yawyaw1 , you're welcome. I couldn't understand what you exactly need. Can you rephrase it within an individual new question similar to this one. Have a nice day!

Comment: Done !
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72426983/change-output-name-after-jolt-transformation